# How to use a `bit build` in a react app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bit

I'm having some troubles exposing my components in [bit](https://bit.dev/)

I have created a react-app with typescript, using: `npx create-react-app my-app --templates typescript`
Then I have created this component:

**..\components\TaskForm\types.ts**

```
export interface ITaskFormTask{
    [key:string]:string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

export interface ITaskFormProps {
    addANewTask: (task: ITaskFormTask) => void;
}

export interface ITaskFormState {
    task: ITaskFormTask;
    showError: boolean;
}
```

**..\components\TaskForm\index.tsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as TYPES from './types';

export {TYPES as TaskFormTypes};

export class TaskForm extends Component<TYPES.ITaskFormProps, TYPES.ITaskFormState> {
    private emptyTask:TYPES.ITaskFormTask = {description: "", title: ""};

    constructor(props: TYPES.ITaskFormProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            task: this.emptyTask,
            showError: false
        };
    }

    private handleNewTask(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>):void {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newTask: TYPES.ITaskFormTask = {
            title: this.state.task.title,
            description: this.state.task.description
        };
        this.props.addANewTask(newTask);

        this.setState({
            task: this.emptyTask
        });
    }

    private handleOnChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>):void {
        let {name, value} = e.target;
        let task:TYPES.ITaskFormTask = Object.assign({}, this.state.task);
        task[name] = value;        
        this.setState({task});
    }
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div className="card card-body">
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleNewTask(e)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="TaskTitle"
                            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
                            value={this.state.task.title} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <textarea
                            name="description"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Task description"
                            value={this.state.task.description}
                            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)} ></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is a simple form with 2 fields and 1 button. I can run the project with no problem with `npm start` and it display the form. I have not posted the App.tsx, because it's irrelevant for the problem.

[image]

Now I want to export my component using bit. As I'm using typescript, I need a the bit compiler. So, first, I have imported it:

`bit import -c bit.envs/compilers/react-typescript`

Then when I try to build it using `bit build` it throws the next exception

```
error: bit failed to build <my_name>.poc_collection/task-form@1.0.0 with the following exception:
Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:142:28
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at findMainFile (C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:137:21)
    at C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:120:32
    at step (C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Proyectos\bit\poc_collection\.git\bit\components\compilers\react-typescript\bit.envs\3.1.16\components\.dependencies\compilers\typescript\bit.envs\3.1.12\dist\ts-compiler\src\compile.js:4:58)
```

Comment: Also running into the same issue, any updates?

Comment: @AmitFeldman not yet. I have openned a ticket on git: https://github.com/teambit/envs/issues/46

Comment: Okay so I found a quick fix. Go to the compile.js where the error is thrown. On line 160 where they create the pathPrefix the code is: var pathPrefix = "" + compDistRoot + (compDistRoot.endsWith('/') ? '' : '/'); I changed it to var pathPrefix = "" + compDistRoot + (compDistRoot.endsWith('\\') ? '' : '\\'); and it should work. I think it might be an issue because were on Windows